# Android Folder in flutter shows errors but the app is running

Tags: android, flutter

In the problem tab of vsVode I got  this,

The app is running successfully but shows this

```
The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\Users\IDRISS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\d146c9752a26f79b52047fb6dc6ed385d064e120494f96f08ca63a317c41f94c.gradle' (C:\Users\Idris Saddi\.gradle\caches\7.4.2\scripts\7s4n1zerenary6wu67e7f3xej).
Could not compile initialization script 'C:\Users\IDRISS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\d146c9752a26f79b52047fb6dc6ed385d064e120494f96f08ca63a317c41f94c.gradle'.
startup failed:
General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 63
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 63
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:199)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:180)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:287)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmDecompiler.parseClass(AsmDecompiler.java:81)
    at ...
1 error
```